# Program to find pythogorean triplet whose sum is 1000, cannot figure out why it doesn't work?

Tags: java, math

```
import java.util.*;
public class Euler9
{
    public static void main (String[] args) 
    {
        double a=3, b=4, c=5;
        double pdt=0;
        int i;
        for(i=0;i<=500000;i++)
        {
            if ((a*a)+(b*b)==(c*c))
            {
                System.out.println("a = "+a+" b = "+b+" c = "+c+" is a pyth tripl.");
                if ((a+b+c)==1000.0)
                {
                    pdt=a*b*c;
                    break;
                }
            }
            a++;
            b++;
            c++;
        }
        System.out.println(pdt);
    }
}
```

Hey, I've been trying to do a few Euler problems for a class I'm taking, and this is my solution is Euler9, https://projecteuler.net/problem=9 but for some reason I cannot get this code to work. Regardless of the value I set i to it seems to end after a single iteration and I cannot figure out why for the life of me. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Why in the world would you use doubles for `a`, `b` and `c`? Try looking at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_triple under "Generating Triple", there you can see that you cannot simply increment `a`, `b` and `c` by one in each step and expect to find all triples!

Comment: I see now that my understanding of what a triple is was flawed. I was under the assumption that a,b,c were three consecutive natural numbers that satisfied the condition (a^2+b^2=c^2). I apologize for my ignorance. As for the variables being doubles, I initially had them as ints, but tried what I could to get what I thought was a proper program to work. Thank you for the response. @JensBoldsen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could reduce your code a lot if you did something like this using multiple for loops, also I don't think this task requires the use of `double` or importing `java.util.*;` when you are not using it at all:

```
class Euler9 {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int sum = 1000;
    for(int a = 1; a <= sum/3; a++) {
      for (int b = a + 1; b <= sum/2; b++) {
        int c = sum - a - b;
        if (a*a + b*b == c*c) {
          System.out.format("a=%d, b=%d, c=%d\n", a, b, c);
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Output:**

```
a=200, b=375, c=425
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed response, even including improvisations. I've learned a lot simply from going through it line by line. I appreciate you taking the time :)

Answer (score 0):

You are incrementing `a`, `b`, `c` all at the same time.

In essence, you're only tring out

- 3^2 + 4^2 = 5^2
- 4^2 + 5^2 = 6^2
- 5^2 + 6^2 = 7^2
- 6^2 + 7^2 = 8^2
- ...
- 100^2 + 101^2 = 102^2
- and so on...

While brute-force algorithm (simply trying every option possible) is not the best approach, you might want to try incrementing a,b,c in separate loops if you want to stick to your approach.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I've learned the actual definiton of a pythogorean triplet and am adjusting my code accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You can't increment all of them at once. You could do something like

```
for(int a = 0; a < 100; a++)
    for(int b = 0; b < 100; b++)
        for(int c = 0; c < 100; c++)
           if(a^2 + b^2 == c^2)
              ...
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. I've learned the actual definiton of a pythogorean triplet and am adjusting my code accordingly.